# ddl statement saved in clob variable over dblink

Tags: plsql, ddl, oracle12c, dblink

I have a problem with executing ddl statement over a db link. 
Below PL/SQL is responsible for executing statement on remote db over the db link, but I need to have ddl_statement variable as clob because maximum varchar2 is not enough for it. Currently it is raising:

PLS-00564: Lob arguments are not permitted in calls to remote server

```
DECLARE
  vi_handler        INTEGER;
  vi_numberOfRows   INTEGER;
BEGIN
  vi_handler := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor%s;
  DBMS_SQL.parse%s (vi_handler, :ddl_statement, DBMS_SQL.native);
  vi_numberOfRows := DBMS_SQL.execute%s (vi_handler);
  DBMS_SQL.close_cursor%s (vi_handler);
END;
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Alex, Yes, it is. I have tryed VARCHAR2(32767)

Comment: Seems like an odd set-up. Is there a maximum size it can reasonably be? Are you able to create a procedure on the remote DB? If so you could create a wrapper procedure there that does the calls to `dbms_sql` locally (on the far end), you could then have multiple varchar2 arguments to that (how many depends on the max size you expect) - and split the CLOB into 32K chunks for the remote call, which are then reassembled into a CLOB for the dynamic calls the other end?

Comment: I can't create a procedure on the remote. I don't know maximum size of statement and it's why I want to use clob. Those ddls are packages, may be it is some way to create package using dblink?

Comment: You can create packages on the remote node, but not procedures?

Comment: I get that you don't know the actual fixed maximum, but presumably you can be pretty sure it won't be 4G, and could live with a lower limit; if you could reasonably say it would never exceed 320KB then you could split into 10 chunks, for example, and have your procedure take 10 arguments to reassemble. It's a moot point though if you can't create a procedure (or package!?) on the remote DB.

Comment: BobC, 
yes, I do not have the consent of the client to create procedures. The task is transfer packages from one db to another.

Alex,
I am pretty sure that it would never exceed 320KB, but as I wrote above, I can't create procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is painful, and would be simpler if you could have a procedure on the remote end that you could call (I know you can't!); but with a bit of effort you can run an anonymous block remotely instead, and have that anonymous block run your DDL.

This is confusing because you need to execute `dbms_sql` calls on the remote DB via an anonymous block running at that end; **and** you need to execute `dbms_sql` calls on the local DB in order to run the anonymous block remotely.

For now I've prefixed the variables etc. on the remote end with `r_`, and at the local end with `l_`. I'm not sure that's enough to help make things clear, but it's a start.

Let's being with a version of what you're attempting, using a local CLOB with a simple package call instead of real DDL:

```
declare
  l_stmt clob;
  l_c pls_integer;
  l_rc pls_integer;
begin
  l_stmt := 'begin dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(user); end;';

  l_c := dbms_sql.open_cursor@dblink;
  dbms_sql.parse@dblink(l_c, l_stmt, dbms_sql.native);
  l_rc := dbms_sql.execute@dblink(l_c);
  dbms_sql.close_cursor@dblink(l_c);
end;
/
```

As expected that gets:

```
ORA-06550: line 9, column 31:
PLS-00564: lob arguments are not permitted in calls to remote server
```

As suggested in a comment, maybe I can split the CLOB up into chunks and reassemble it. If I was actually on the remote server I could do something like this, manually chopping my statement up for now:

```
var b1 varchar2(20);
var b2 varchar2(20);
var b3 varchar2(20);

exec :b1 := 'begin dbms_stats.gat';
exec :b2 := 'her_schema_stats(use';
exec :b3 := 'r); end;';

declare
  r_stmt clob := :b1 || :b2 || :b3;
  r_c pls_integer;
  r_rc pls_integer;
begin
  r_c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(r_c, r_stmt, dbms_sql.native);
  r_rc := dbms_sql.execute(r_c);
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(r_c);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

So now I want to run the same thing remotely. That anonymous block becomes the statement that is parsed locally:

```
declare
  l_stmt clob;
  l_remote_stmt varchar2(32767);
  l_c integer;
  l_rc integer;
begin
  l_stmt := 'begin dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(user); end;';

  l_remote_stmt := q'[
declare
  r_stmt clob := :b1 || :b2 || :b3;
  r_c pls_integer;
  r_rc pls_integer;
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  r_c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(r_c, r_stmt, dbms_sql.native);
  r_rc := dbms_sql.execute(r_c);
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(r_c);
end;
]';

  l_c := dbms_sql.open_cursor@dblink;
  dbms_sql.parse@dblink(l_c, l_remote_stmt, dbms_sql.native);
  -- bind the chunks of CLOB
  dbms_sql.bind_variable@dblink(l_c, 'B1', dbms_lob.substr(l_stmt, 20, 1));
  dbms_sql.bind_variable@dblink(l_c, 'B2', dbms_lob.substr(l_stmt, 20, 21));
  dbms_sql.bind_variable@dblink(l_c, 'B3', dbms_lob.substr(l_stmt, 20, 41));
  -- execute the anonymous block (which makes its own dbms_sql calls) remotely
  l_rc := dbms_sql.execute@dblink(l_c);
  dbms_sql.close_cursor@dblink(l_c);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I've used 20-char chunks to mimic what I did manually earlier. For your real DDL you would do:

```
  dbms_sql.bind_variable@dblink(l_c, 'B1', dbms_lob.substr(l_stmt, 32767, 1));
  dbms_sql.bind_variable@dblink(l_c, 'B2', dbms_lob.substr(l_stmt, 32767, 32768));
  dbms_sql.bind_variable@dblink(l_c, 'B3', dbms_lob.substr(l_stmt, 32767, 65535));
```

... possibly calculating the offset instead of manually entering it. For large CLOBs add more concatenated bind variables to the remote statement, and matching `bind_variable` calls.

This version determines how many chunks the CLOB will need to be split into, and creates an appropriate remote statement, and does the binding in the same manner:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_stmt clob;
  l_remote_stmt varchar2(32767);
  l_remote_args varchar2(4000);
  l_c integer;
  l_rc integer;
begin
  -- create valid dummy statement > 32k via comments
  l_stmt := 'begin dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(user); /* ';
  -- random garbage as comments
  for i in 1..20 loop
    l_stmt := l_stmt || dbms_random.string('a', 4000);
  end loop;
  l_stmt := l_stmt || ' */ end;';
  -- for debug only
  dbms_output.put_line('l_stmt size: ' || length(l_stmt)
    || ' chunks ' || ceil(length(l_stmt)/32767));

  -- build remote bind list dynamically
  l_remote_args := ' to_clob(:b1)';
  for i in 2..ceil(length(l_stmt)/32767) loop
    l_remote_args := l_remote_args || ' || to_clob(:b' || i || ')';
  end loop;
  -- for debug only
  dbms_output.put_line('l_remote_args: ' || l_remote_args);

  -- build remote statement, including constructed list of binds
  l_remote_stmt := q'[
declare
  r_stmt clob := ]' || l_remote_args || q'[;
  r_c pls_integer;
  r_rc pls_integer;
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  r_c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(r_c, r_stmt, dbms_sql.native);
  r_rc := dbms_sql.execute(r_c);
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(r_c);
end;
]';

  l_c := dbms_sql.open_cursor@dblink3;

  -- parse full remote statement including generated binds  
  dbms_sql.parse@dblink3(l_c, l_remote_stmt, dbms_sql.native);

  -- bind variables using chunks of original CLOB
  for i in 1..ceil(length(l_stmt)/32767) loop
    dbms_sql.bind_variable@dblink3(l_c, 'B' || i,
      dbms_lob.substr(l_stmt, 32767, ((i-1) * 32767) + 1));
    l_remote_args := l_remote_args || ' || :b' || i;
  end loop;
  l_rc := dbms_sql.execute@dblink3(l_c);

  dbms_sql.close_cursor@dblink3(l_c);
end;
/

l_stmt size: 80055 chunks 3
l_remote_args:  to_clob(:b1) || to_clob(:b2) || to_clob(:b3)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! I will try something similar, but tomorrow. I will let you know

Comment: @vis - added a more flexible version you may just be able to plug your real DDL into (instead of the dummy `l_stmt` I'm generating).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this, it might be helpful.
https://github.com/HowdPrescott/Lob_Over_DBLink

Thanks @Phonolog, understood.
And you're right, it doesn't actually answer the question, but was a direction to something that might help.

So how about this.
Could you use the dbms_sql parse overload with the dbms_sql.varchar2a type (a table of varchar2(32767))?
As per this example:

```
DECLARE  
  vi_handler        INTEGER;  
  vi_numberOfRows   INTEGER;  
  ddl_statement     DBMS_SQL.varchar2a@some_dblink;  
BEGIN  
  ddl_statement(1) := 'create or replace function get_dual return varchar2 as ';  
  ddl_statement(2) := 'v_dual varchar2(1);';  
  ddl_statement(3) := 'begin ';  
  ddl_statement(4) := '    select * into v_dual from dual;';  
  ddl_statement(5) := '    return v_dual;';  
  ddl_statement(6) := 'end get_dual;';  
  vi_handler := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor@some_dblink;  
  DBMS_SQL.parse@some_dblink (vi_handler, ddl_statement, 1, ddl_statement.count, true, DBMS_SQL.native);  
  vi_numberOfRows := DBMS_SQL.execute@some_dblink (vi_handler);  
  DBMS_SQL.close_cursor@some_dblink (vi_handler);  
END;
```

Comment: Hi there. Although a link is often helpful, an answer should contain some more explanations see [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I do this by writing the DDL to a file, then using sqlplus to include the file. Here is an example of my distributing an administrative package to all of my Oracle instances:

> c:\temp\distribute.sql holds my DDL
>
> ```
> sqlplus /nolog
> connect /@db1 as sysdba
> @c:\temp\distribute.sql
> connect /@db2 as sysdba
> @c:\temp\distribute.sql
> ...
> connect /@dbN as sysdba
> @c:\temp\distribute.sql
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help. I have sent package which is responsible for executing ddls 
to remote server over dblink(that package fit in varchar2) and then I am getting packages sourec from all_source over dblink from 1. db. it is working because one line of package is on record in view.